# How to determine if the request is coming from a particular windows domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, windowsdomainaccount

I am developing a web application with MVC-3

I want to give the users of a particular windows domain some special privileges; therefore I have to determine whether the request is coming from that particular domain.

Please note that I am using Forms authentication.

I know that I can do this by tracking the IP address of the user. But **is there a way to directly get the domain name?**

For example, if the user is logged in as `ADomain\AUsername` in a windows machine, is there a way to get `ADomain`?

Comment: [How to Use Forms Authentication with Active Directory in Multiple Domains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650307.aspx)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It says *"This content is outdated and is no longer being maintained...."*. Should I continue with this?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - the techniques described there don't work in IIS7 or greater.

Comment: Well, you might look into Single Sign-On then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, maybe and sometimes.  First, only Internet Explorer passes credentials through to the server.  Second, the server must be on the same domain as the client, third there can't be any proxies or other things in between.  Both computer and client must be on the same network as well.

Even with all that, it still only works sometimes.  What version of IIS?  If it's IIS7 or greater, then there are other issues where you can't combine forms authentication and windows authentication.  If you're using IIS6, then it might be able to be done, but it's a huge pain.

In practice, I wouldn't bother.. it's just too much effort for saving the users from typing in their username and password.

Comment: *it's just too much effort for saving the users from typing in their username and password.* Yes, yes it is. I think I should simply avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

You can get domain name using UrlReferrer of the request object.

```
string Domain Name = Request.UrlReferrer.Host;
```

Also if you want to check in your application that whether the request is coming from different domain or not then please try to verify the hostname of the URL referrer with the hostname of your own application URL. Please use the below code

```
(if Request.Url.Host != Request.UrlReferrer.Host)
{
}
```

Comment: Not what the OP is asking for.